# Remote desktop access (VNC) in China - how to get it working

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop, vnc

I am trying to get remote desktop access via VNC from and to a windows7 machine working. The computer where the TigerVNC server is running (the usermode variant, the other wasn't working), is located in China, while I'm based in Europe. I mention this since you often hear about internet problems with regards to China.
I previously tested TigerVNC server + client between computers in our internal network to make sure I am generally using the software correctly.

I did this:
On the target computer, TigerVNC server is installed and made start after windows startup. In their router setup, a port forwarding for port 5900 was added - the default for VNC and that wasn't changed.
I also had them disable the windows firewall.

Then I attempted to connect to their machine with TigerVNC Viewer, having them tell what "whatsmyip" returns from their machine to know their external IP.
The viewer gave this error: "**unable to connect to socket: Connection timed out (10060)**"

According to a forum entry elsewhere, this error means that that IP address does not respond at all, which means either wrong IP or firewall is blocking.
Which is weird, given my above previous steps.
Also, executing "ping [address]" from cmd results in timeout / 100% packet loss.
(their IP changes daily, so I wanted to connect with today's IP & VNC to setup dynDNS there to get permanent remote access)

What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If possible. Ask someone at the location to install no-ip or similar so that you have a dns that autoupdates to the servers ip. That way you can minimize the risk that you have the wrong ip.

You can also try an open port tool to see if the port really is open to the internet.

http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/